# jquery datatables with ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, datatables

I'm getting `"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - ..."` when trying to load `Datatable` using `ajax`, I see 'allow': 'put' in the header, wonder if it has anything to do with it?

**HTML**

```
<table id="my-equipments">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Equipment Number</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Location</th>
   <th>Description</th>   
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#my-equipments").dataTable({
    "ajax": "/myapp/equipments/datatable"
});
}
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/equipments/datatable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
EquipmentDatatable getEquipmentsDatatable(Model model,
        HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
...
}
```

**Firebug**
[image]

Comment: Did you try to `PUT` (leaving aside that it's the wrong HTTP method for retrieval)? ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir, I'm sorry, not following you. I'm not tinkering with the jQuery .ajax, as you can see making a 'high level' call, letting Datatables do the .ajax and it's options.

Comment: Well, you need to debug obviously and from the information provided there's not much one can do from here. Does a `PUT` request (e.g. done manually from the browser console) return the data you expect? Are there any strange settings you overlooked? Is there something misconfigured? What are the request headers? Is the right function in the right controller called? …